# Post request to golang server using polymer core-ajax?

Tags: ajax, post, curl, go, polymer

I am trying to make a POST request using polymer core-ajax to server runnung golang. After a lot of search (because i am new to this stuff) i ended up with the following code. Also, GET request is working perfect. POST parameters i dont understand how to pass using core-ajax.

```
<polymer-element name="register-user" attributes="url">
    <template>
        <core-ajax id="ajaxSubmit" url="{{url}}" contentType="application/json" handleAs="json" method="post" on-core-response="{{response}}"></core-ajax>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({
        buttonListener: function() {
            var data = '{"Name":"'+ this.name +'", "Email":"'+ this.email +'"}';
            this.$.ajaxSubmit.data = data;
            this.$.ajaxSubmit.go();
            console.log(data);
        },
        response: function(oldValue){
            console.log(this.response);
        }
    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

above code returns `500 (Internal Server Error)` however when i make a POST request using curl i.e

```
curl -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"Name":"Batman",    
     "Email":"batman@gmail.com"}' http://so.me.ip.ad:8080/register
```

it works as it should and returns

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
X-Powered-By: go-json-rest
Date: Wed, 29 Apr 2015 05:40:15 GMT
Content-Length: 117

{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Batman",
  "email": "batman@gmail.com",
  "createdAt": "2015-04-29T05:40:15.073491143Z"
}
```

also, i have a CORS middleware set up on server i.e

```
api.Use(&rest.CorsMiddleware{
    RejectNonCorsRequests: false,
    OriginValidator: func(origin string, request *rest.Request) bool {
        return origin == "http://0.0.0.0:8000"
    },
    AllowedMethods: []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT"},
    AllowedHeaders: []string{
        "Accept", "Content-Type", "X-Custom-Header", "Origin"},
    AccessControlAllowCredentials: true,
    AccessControlMaxAge:           3600,
})
```

What am i doing wrong? Any feedback will be of great help! Thanks ^.^

Edit : here is a little more info if it can help.. [image: screenshot]

Comment: Browsers usually also send headers like "User-Agent" and "Referer" and those are not listed as allowed headers in your CORS middelware - perhaps thats the problem?

Comment: @ain i added "User-Agent" and "Referer" as AllowedHeaders but still get a 500 in response :(

Comment: What go packages do you use ?  Try dumping (in the Go server) the complete request (e.g : all Headers and content) to inspect what is different between your `curl` request and your polymer request.

Comment: Did you try setting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to '*'?

Comment: Does it help setting the headers?this.$.ajax.headers='{"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"'};

Comment: @Niels Drost  I'm away from computer, will try that and get back here asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think CORS is a red herring. The problem may be that you are sending the data form-encoded and not as json. I found a bug from a user with a [similar problem](https://github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest/issues/105).

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: application/json
X-Powered-By: go-json-rest
Date: Fri, 12 Dec 2014 04:29:59 GMT
Content-Length: 71

{
  "Error": "invalid character '\\'' looking for beginning of value"
}
```

Perhaps you should use `.body` instead of `.data`? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898357/polymer-core-ajax-wont-post-json?answertab=votes#24898458).

From the polymer [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-ajax.html):

> body: Optional raw body content to send when method === "POST".
>
> Example:

```
<core-ajax method="POST" auto url="http://somesite.com"
    body='{"foo":1, "bar":2}'>
</core-ajax>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! i had to work around CORS though (moved my polymer code on same domain)